# is there a way to do margin-right auto (always move div to right)

Tags: html, css

is there a way to do margin-right auto (always move div to right). I tried margin-right: auto; and margin: 0 0 0 auto; didn't work.

Comment: float:right; is not what I want. I just want margin or padding so that the div will always start on the right end side

Comment: you need margin-left auto if you want the element on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin-left: 100%`. If you want to define other margin values, you can use the shorthand `margin: 0 0 0 100%`, for example. This will "push" the div to the right of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Margin parameter work like this :

margin : top, right, bottom, and left,

So it should be: `0 auto 0 0`

by the way flex is also a very nice position :

```css
 .one{
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color:red;
 }
    
 .element-right{
    width: 50px;
    background-color:  blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="one">
     <div class="element-right">BOX</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that as well with a little help from a wrapper over your original `div`:

HTML:

```
<div class="right-wrapper">
   <div class="right">

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right-wrapper {
   text-align: right;
}
.right {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This works because the contents of the parent `.right-wrapper` are set to behave like text while keeping their block behavior (`display: inline-block`). This causes the child `div` to react to parent's `text-align: right`.

In some cases you might find that the child div is inheriting a width property and is full width. It's useful to then set child's `width` property to `auto` in case the child element is supposed to be some sort of a button or other, smaller element aligned to the right side.

```
.right {
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `text-align` method on divs

```
.parent{
 text-align: right
}
.child{
 display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.parent .child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```